# Xshell can not connect to the VM, but can ping it

Tags: centos, networking, virtual-machine

I use the Xshell, in it I can ping the VM's IP address(NAT model).

```
[c:\~]$ ping 45.117.42.131

正在 Ping 45.117.42.131 具有 32 字节的数据:
来自 45.117.42.131 的回复: 字节=32 时间<1ms TTL=128
来自 45.117.42.131 的回复: 字节=32 时间<1ms TTL=128
来自 45.117.42.131 的回复: 字节=32 时间<1ms TTL=128
来自 45.117.42.131 的回复: 字节=32 时间<1ms TTL=128

45.117.42.131 的 Ping 统计信息:
    数据包: 已发送 = 4，已接收 = 4，丢失 = 0 (0% 丢失)，
往返行程的估计时间(以毫秒为单位):
    最短 = 0ms，最长 = 0ms，平均 = 0ms
```

But I can not connect to the IP (`45.117.42.131`):

```
[c:\~]$ ssh root@45.117.42.131


Connecting to 45.117.42.131:22...
Could not connect to '45.117.42.131' (port 22): Connection failed.
```

In the VM I have disabled/stoped the selinux and firewalld.
And I can also ping the www.google.com in the VM.

VM system is CentOS 7.2.

And this below is the NIC config of the IP（ifcfg-eno33554960）:

[image]

### (I only can post snapshoot, because I can not copy the code in the VMware)

**EDIT**

I checked the `sshd` use the `ps` command:

[image]

---

**EDIT -2**

But if I use the:

```
service sshd status
```

it shows the `sshd.service` is running(active), you see the upper EDIT is `Ss` status.

---

**EDIT-3**

iptables:

[image]

---

**EDIT-4**

netstat -nltp shows below:

[image]

Comment: Is `sshd` running?

Comment: It is the `Ss` status, when  I check.

Comment: @thrig See my EDIT, the `service sshd status` is running.

Comment: Make sure if your vendor turn off remote root login when building your virtual server.And, if possible, post your ssh_config file content in /etc/ssh/ssh_config.There is a directive called PermitRootLogin=No(default is no) in ssh_config file.Please update if you post the file content.

Comment: Post your current firewall status using --> iptables -L (which needs iptables to be installed in advance,and iptables-services as an additional managing package).The related iptables command of allowing 22 port on your virtual server is --> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: @FrontENG  `#PermitRootLogin=Yes`, and it is annotation, and for iptables see my newest EDIT

Comment: Can you post a list using (netstat -ntlp) to make sure port 22 is listening by sshd?

Comment: @FrontENG See my EDIT 4

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT .And see if it would work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61912/discussion-between-fronteng-and-aircraft).

Comment: is this problem fixed?

Comment: @FrontENG no, I can not , I deleted the VM, build a new One.